# Determining the composition $f(h(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)= 12(8x+3)$
$h(x)= (3x+19)-5$

I really need step by step directions to solve $f(h(x))$.

Also can someone solve $h(f(x))$.

I really need help this is so confusing. I am able to do the simpler ones but not a question ever this challenging.

Comment: Replace $x$ with $(3x+19)-5$ in the definition of $f(x)$.

Comment: I was just messing around and I accidentally saved it and I couldn't change it back so THANK YOU! and I'm sorry @Thursday

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Think of the rule for $f$ as
$$f(\square)=12(8\square +3)$$

Now write the expression for $h(x)$ in each box to get a formula for $f(h(x))$.

Next, do the same thing for $h$.

Comment: Directions unclear, $\square$ got stuck in a toaster.

Comment: $$f(\boxed{h(x)})=f(\underbrace{\boxed{h(x)}}_{\textrm{this is }h(x)})=12(8\underbrace{\boxed{(3x+19)-5}}_{\textrm{this is }h(x)}+3)$$

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put $h(x)$ where there is $x$ in $f(x)$.

$$f(h(x))=12(8h(x)+3)$$
$$=12(8(3x+19)+3)$$

And then you only need to complete the details.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = 12(8x + 3)$$ $$h(x) = (3x + 19) - 5$$.

What do we mean when we say $f(h(x))$? It means we evaluate $f$ *at* $h(x)$. In other words, the value that we plug into $f(x)$ is whatever $h(x)$ is.  In this case, we know that $h(x) = (3x + 19) - 5$, so we're going to plug that into the variable for $f(x)$.

So $$f(h(x)) = 12(8((3x + 19) - 5) + 3)$$

Now we can simplify this:

$$12(8((3x + 19) - 5) + 3) = 12(8(3x + 14) + 3) = 12(24x + 112) = 288x + 1344$$

For $h(f(x))$, we simply do the opposite.  Take $f(x)$ and plug it into the variable for $h(x)$, so we have $$h(f(x)) = (3(12(8x + 3)) + 19) - 5 = (3(96x + 36) + 19) = 288x + 108 + 19 = 288x + 127$$

It is, of course, advised to go through this process too and check my calculations, as I am not a computer and I'm typing this half asleep, but the process still stands.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I was just really confused cuz the equations were different so I didn't know what to do

Comment: In general, $f(h(x))$ will not equal $h(f(x))$.